# AcceptButton for each group of controls in different tabs, Can't use some envents in Combobox to make it AcceptButton

Tags: c#, visual-studio, winforms

I have different tabs on my UserControl. Each tab has some controls and button. I want to change AcceptButton on the basis of group of controls I am in.

I can use TextChanged event or Enter event to make a button AcceptButton for Textboxes but I have some Comboboxes too. These combos are auto complete so I can't user Enter event on these, because on Enter these combos should be completed.

Following image can explain my problem more.

[alt text http://img258.imageshack.us/img258/9163/acceptbutton.png](http://img258.imageshack.us/img258/9163/acceptbutton.png)

Thanks.

Comment: Did my answer help you at all? If not would you mind posting your solution?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest adding a handler to the SelectedIndexChanged event on the tab control and doing something like this:

```
private void tabControl1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    switch (tabControl1.SelectedIndex)
    {
        case 0:
            AcceptButton = button1;
            break;
        case 1:
            AcceptButton = button2;
            break;
    }
}
```

This is much more reliable than trying to work out what tab you are on using enter and exit events on the individual controls within the tabs.